# Retrieve & Preview the Attribute Values stored in IEnumerable<> in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to retrieve & preview the name & values of attributes (credentials) stored in `IEnumerable<CredentialPreviewAttribute> CredentialAttributesValues`

By running a loop `foreach (var item in _credential.CredentialAttributesValues)`, if I print it on console e.g. `Console.WriteLine()`, I get the name and value for all the attributes. But If I want to preview (output) it on screen (using xml), it only returns the last attribute name and value.

The mobile application received the credentials from web application, which is stored in

**CredentialRecord.cs**

```
public class CredentialRecord : RecordBase
{
    public CredentialRecord();

    public string CredentialDefinitionId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CredentialPreviewAttribute> CredentialAttributesValues { get; set; }
    public string SchemaId { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionId { get; set; }
    public string CredentialId { get; set; }
    public CredentialState State { get; set; }
}
```

I'm able to retrieve the `SchemaID`, `CredentialId` e.t.c, except `public IEnumerable<CredentialPreviewAttribute> CredentialAttributesValues { get; set; }`, in which the `Name`, `PassportNumber` e.t.c is stored.

```
public class CredentialPreviewAttribute
{
    public CredentialPreviewAttribute();
    public CredentialPreviewAttribute(string name, string value);

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string MimeType { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I run the foreach loop, but it only returned the first item value.

**CredentialPage.xml**

```
        <ListView
            SeparatorVisibility="None"
            BackgroundColor="#004B86"
            ItemsSource="{Binding CredentialAttributes}"
            HasUnevenRows="true">
        </ListView>
```

**CredentialViewModel.cs**

```
namespace Osma.Mobile.App.ViewModels.Credentials
{
    public class CredentialViewModel : ABaseViewModel
    {
        private readonly CredentialRecord _credential;
        private readonly ICredentialService _credentialService;

        public CredentialViewModel(
            ICredentialService credentialService,
            CredentialRecord credential
        ) : base(
            nameof(CredentialViewModel)
        )
        {
            _credential = credential;

            // Loop to Preview the Credentials
            foreach (var item in _credential.CredentialAttributesValues)
            {
                _credentialAttributes = item.Value.ToString();
            }
        }

        #region Bindable Properties
        private string _credentialAttributes;
        public string CredentialAttributes
        {
            get => _credentialAttributes;
            set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _credentialAttributes, value);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220609/discussion-on-question-by-joe-doe-retrieve-preview-the-attribute-values-stored).

Comment: If you get all the values with `Console.WriteLine` but not with the xml you are probably creating the xml wrong. Like overwriting each item in the loop so you will only get the last one. Can you show how you are creating the xml?

Comment: `CredentialPage.xml` is where I create a `<ListView>`.. I pasted code for this above.. if u need complete page, I will paste it.

Comment: Can you fix the binding names n repost it? it's confusing to suggest you something... you have to use linq query n Notify property for data change n data selection

Comment: @Blu I updated the code, kindly have a look.. is this what you meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding to a `string`, that's why you only get the one item, try using an `ObservableCollection` instead:

```
public class CredentialViewModel : ABaseViewModel
{
    private readonly CredentialRecord _credential;
    private readonly ICredentialService _credentialService;

    public CredentialViewModel(
        ICredentialService credentialService,
        CredentialRecord credential
    ) : base(
        nameof(CredentialViewModel)
    )
    {
        _credential = credential;

        // Loop to Preview the Credentials
        foreach (var item in _credential.CredentialAttributesValues)
        {
            _credentialAttributes.Add(item.Value.ToString());
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> _credentialAttributes = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public ObservableCollection<string> CredentialAttributes
    {
        get
        {
            return _credentialAttributes;
        }
        set
        {
            this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _credentialAttributes, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry my bad.. I removed `ItemTemplate="{StaticResource credentialAttributeTemplateSelector}"` from `ListView` in xml and it worked..

Comment: one question.. I received 12 attributes.. some are empty.. if I want to just output the non-empty or let's say, 5 Attributes of my choice.. how would I do that?

Comment: You could bind to the object instead of a string and use a converter to display in any way you want: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters